# What is right grammatically between the two sentences?

Tags: word-choice, tense

Context:

> 1. The research has yet to give the best result.
> 2. The research is yet to give the best result.

Comment: There is no context — you've given us just the two sentences. And I'm not sure that either makes much sense.

Comment: My gut tells me that "has yet" works better than "is yet". More importantly, though, you should heed Luke's advice, and provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is used more and correct.

The second sentence sounds very strange although could possible be correct. I’m sorry, I don’t have any English grammar rules as to why either are correct or incorrect; however, as a native English speaker, I can tell you that the first sentence is correct.